# html submit data which not in Text Fields

Tags: html, django

I need display a table contain text field and button like:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>icon</td>
        <td>    </td>
    </tr>
{% for i in gs %}
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>{{ i.id }}</td>
        <td align='center'>{{ i.name }}</td>
        <td align='center'><input type="text" name="icon" value="{{ i.icon }}" /></td>
        <td align='center'><input type=submit value="update" style="width:100%"></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If user want to modify 'icon', then input new value in the text field and click update. But the problem is in django function, I only gets 'icon' value in 'request.POST', I don't know which id is updating. So how to pass 'i.id' into POST with icon together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add hidden input field in the form to get id. In your template add another input field

```
<td align='center'><input type="text" name="icon" value="{{ i.icon }}" /></td>
<td align='center'><input type="hidden" name="icon_id" value="{{ i.id }}" /></td>
```

Then your view you will have `icon_id` field in submitted data.